# Should there be spaces between a number and its measurement unit?

Tags: word-usage

Not sure if this is a style problem or a grammar problem

- 64 m
- 59.8 km
- 210 ft
- 37.2 mi

Are spaces necessary between digits and measurement unit?

Comment: It's purely a style issue.

Comment: This has nothing to do with grammar.  Grammar is syntax and morphology, not orthography or typesetting.

Answer (score 7):

It's a typography/style problem. Spaces are required before 'normal' (letter-based) units in all English style guides I have seen. Sometimes, however, using a *thin* space is recommended.

Comment: @StuW No, a space after _%_ would just be silly—you’d end up with things like “nearly 25 %of all people”. ;-þ

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: No, _no_ space after % would be silly :-D

Comment: @phresnel Bugger! You try to be clever, and boom, you get hit by Skitt’s Law! :-\

Comment: If we're dealing with computers, I'd strongly recommend a no-break space.

Comment: My bad! Obviously I meant no space *before* percent symbol. 23%

Answer (score 6):

[The NIST Checklist for Reviewing Manuscripts: SI Unit rules and style conventions](http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/checklist.html) specifies in rule #15 that there should be a space except for superscript units like degrees, and a normal "-", like normal English, for the spelled-out name in adjectival form, the examples they use are:

> a 25 kg sphere
>   an angle of 2° 3'  4"
>   a roll of 35-millimeter film

A thin space is used (see rule #16 of the same guide) for digit spacing, e.g. "12 345.678 91", this thin space is usually also non-breaking so that the number is typeset on a single line.

Comment: Those are NIST rules for reviewing manuscripts in SI units, not an SI publication.

Comment: @PeteKirkham fixed.